# Deserialize a third party singleton class in Java

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, singleton, deserialization

I am facing an issue in which a third party class is a singleton class and I want to deserialize it. Conventional wisdom says to use `Mixin` from Jackson, but I do not know how to do that for a class that does not provide any constructor. Help appreciated